# How to prevent mysql blobs from borking my terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

When using the linux terminal client for mysql, every column with a blob prints out tons of control characters and the terminal has to be reset.

This looks something like the following

```
   Map: �PNG  IHDR   �      Z=�   tRNS . 8 B��`  gIDATx���yX��ǿ ��B��h-�7Db�.-\�E\Q騵U{��֥�m�?E�IU�u�t
```

�J)Fm�-IY�Z�^�
              ("e���!��� ��Ó��9���|�s�{�,�!�    �?+V�[������
���6�`�} �h��V���e�jWEo� �������݇8B?P/�.������]�<�I~��sJle

However, on another server it prints out nicely, on one line like so

```
          Map: �PNG
```

I can confirm that these are the exact same image, cloned from one server to the other. I assume it is some setting in one of the mysql servers or clients.

To clarify, I know how to reset the terminal. What I really want is to avoid having to specify every field in my select (SELECT *, rather than listing all 15 *non-blob* columns).

How do I make it always appear the second way?

Comment: Why are you spewing out *binary* data? In any case, the solution to unwedging the tty is to type "^jreset^j" (omit the '"', ^j is ctrl-J)

Comment: @vonbrand it is a png image stored in the field as binary. I would rather it not 'spew out', like on the other server.